# How to bring two div in same line

Tags: css, html

I am confused how to bring two div into same line.
I used `float:left` and `float:right` one for each of them and also they are contained as two different `div id` of a `div class`. Also used `display:inline` in class.
Please give any idea regarding this problem.

Comment: please past your html and css code here

Comment: by the way, thanx for trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `float: left` for both of them

Comment: what changes did you make?

Comment: @KaranTewari though the solution is only in my comment, I removed `width` from 1st div and used `float: left`

Answer (score 0):

You can chance the display property to either `inline` or `inline-block`.

For example:

```
<div class="example">One</div><div class="example">Two</div>
```

With

```
.example {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: not working, i also have a background image in first div, does it matters?

Comment: It should work - here is an example with a background: http://jsfiddle.net/raGZD/2/ - can you be more specific about "not working"?

Comment: Sir, i have one div inside that i have two divisions, one has an image, one ul and two paragraphs and in second div i have a normal text and i want both of them to be on same line but my output is coming a bit different, the second division is coming after completion of first one.

Comment: Can you add your HTML to your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to achieve this, and I've detailed seven of them on [a sample page](https://boldewyn.github.io/grid-example/). Tl;dr:

- `float`ing the `div`s (@vladkras' answer)
- Using `display: inline-block;` (@Sohnee's answer)
- Using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/): `display: flex` on the parent
- Playing with negative margin to move the second `div` around
- Using `display: table` on the parent and `display: table-cell` on the children
- Playing around with `position: absolute`
- And, the newest and in many cases best solution, [CSS Grid Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/): `display: grid` on the parent.