# CSS grid: how to bring elements in same grid area to line up?

Tags: css, layout, masonry, css-grid

My target is to use CSS grid layout for a two-column masonry layout of boxes. Given an element with children:

```
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

bring the children to sort themselves alternately into columns. My idea was to have two grid areas `left` and `right` and telling the children to split into them:

```
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "left right";
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  grid-area: left;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  grid-area: right;
}
```

Here's a JSBin that illustrates my current state: https://jsbin.com/zaduruv/edit?html,css,output

Unfortunately, the elements react quite identical to as if they had `position:absolute` set. That is, they all crowd towards the top and overlap one another.

Is there any possibility with the CSS grid layout properties to bring the children to line up in the columns, like they'd do normally with `position: static`?

Comment: have you looked at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/?

Comment: I tried to solve this using flexbox: `https://jsbin.com/tujuzumaca/edit?html,css,output` the only thing you need to make sure is not to give fixed height to the DIVs but to let it take height on its own according to the content.

Comment: @Winter I actually linked to that page in an answer an hour ago ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588420/how-to-bring-two-div-in-same-line/42689423#42689423

Comment: @ANshulSharma I think we misunderstood one another. The aim is for the boxes, that do have different heights based on their content, to be laid flush out one under the other, without gaps. I solved this with flexbox, too, using `flex-direction: column`, but it has the disadvantage, that I need to set a fixed height on the `section`, otherwise the children wouldn't wrap into a second column. Hence my idea to try and use grid layout.

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Since elements can overlap each other in a CSS grid, it doesn't even *try* to align them. As its name suggests, it is a grid, not a column layout.

A better solution would be to use [CSS multi-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts) layout, as the snippet below.

The only problem with the multi-column layout is, that it distributes the divs vertically instead of horizontally, so you get this:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

instead of this:

```
1 2 
3 4
5 6
```

```css
section {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    column-gap: 0;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

div {
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #c1c0c1;
  height: 100px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #fedbc1;
  height: 50px;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #dec34a;
  height: 130px;
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #ce3294;
  height: 110px;
}

div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #99deac;
  height: 80px;
}

div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: #aade34;
  height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I suspected that that's not grid's scope to do something like that. I experimented with CSS columns, too, but ran into issues, where browsers ignored a child's `break-inside: avoid`, and smeared that child's content over two columns.

Comment: I'm inclined right now to just give up, add two wrapper elements and sort the children in there manually. Or getting good ol' Masonry.js back in place.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ditch the grid-areas for this one and work with grid-column-start. Otherwise everything will be put into the same area. https://jsbin.com/peqiwodoba/edit?html,css,output

```
div:nth-child(odd) {
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```